# Ckeditor remove specific plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor on 2 pages. On 1st Page I need all plugins while on 2nd page I only need few of them. I try to find solution and I got this:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font,templates,';
```

in config.js.Now if I add this in `config.js` it disable attributes globally rather than on a specific page. 
How Can I disable plugins on a specific page.
I am doing this to make textarea as ckeditor.

Javascript:

```
<script>
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

CKEDITOR.replace( 'template_body',{
        //extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'

      } );

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="elementbox">
                <label class="form-label">Body<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea name="template_body" id="template_body" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Edit- I even tried these as per all comments but not working.

```
<script>
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

CKEDITOR.replace( 'template_body',{
        //extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'

      } );
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: you can try with window.location.pathname for that specific page inside if condition

Comment: can you pls show me any fiddle?

Comment: what's your specific page path  will be ?

Comment: Do all the affected `textarea`'s have the same ID attribute? If you give it a different ID, you can use a different `CHEDITOR.replace` call for each.

Comment: @BenHillier I have in 2 different pages. SO Obv there will be 2 different id's

Comment: Try to insert after CKEDITOR.replace script in the 2nd page the following:     CKEDITOR.editorConfig(config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font,templates,');

Comment: @liontass I tried ! Unfortunately Not worked !

Comment: Try the new one that I updated and check the console for errors

Comment: Not worked! Sorry !

Comment: Create another config .js file with your requiremejt and refference to this file in your page

Comment: Thats what I have to avoid it. @liontass or else I have done it before only Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot researching I have found a solution for myself.
We can load only specific toolbar as per our need.
As On 2nd Page I need my custom toolbar so I can do this in

config.js

```
config.toolbar_Basic =
    [
        ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']
    ];
```

Where I am loading the ckeditor

HTML

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'template_body',{
        //extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'

    toolbar: 'Basic'
      } );
```

That Will Load only specific toolbar only

Answer (score 0):

Just include the below line in the config.js

```
// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,Source,-,Save,NewPage,DocProps,Preview,Print,Templates'; // append any plugin that you want to hide
```